# No module named 'arcade' in VS Code 2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, arcade

Whenever I try to run my code in Microsoft Visual Code Studio 2, it keeps popping up saying that there is no module named arcade.

However, when I run the code in pyCharm, it runs perfectly fine. Does anyone know why it does this?

[image: Screenshot to show that there is no module named arcade]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm creates virtual environments, if you pip install in pycharm you are not installing for your laptop and if you pip install in vscode you are installing for your laptop but not pycharm.

You need to pip3 install arcade from your command line

Comment: Exact Code, RufusVS: `pip3 install arcade` or if your on Windows OS, try `pip install arcade`

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is an IDE that supports piles and piles of languages. That also means that they could not just keep importing ALL the packages for you, because that would mean that the app will be too big for any system. Also, it will be really inconvenient for the people who made Visual Studio Code. On the other hand, PyCharm only supports Python, which means that importing all the packages for you is not as hard, since they do not need to worry about other packages.

Ask me if you have any more questions.